# How does file processing work in this case?

Tags: python

An "address file"

```
100 Main Street 
23  Spring Park Road 
2012 Sunny Lane 
4 Martin Luther King Drive
```

An "address list"

```
    [['100', 'Main', 'Street'],
 ['23', 'Spring Park', 'Road'], 
 ['2012', 'Sunny', 'Lane'],
 ['4', 'Martin Luther King', 'Drive']]

numbers_file = open("address_file.txt", "r")
def load_addresses(numbers_file):
    addresses = [] # <-- Create a list for sublist
    for line in numbers_file:
        address = [] # <-- Create a sublist 
        parts = line.split() # <-- split into lists by whitespace
        address.append(parts[0]) # <--- I know this will take first elements of the            lists and appended (back of the list) to sublist. 
        name = '' # <--- name to attach such as 'Spring' 'Park' into 'Spring'
        for i in range(1, len(parts) - 1): # <--- Why is the range like this? is it because we ignore first element since its already in good form and since its index we -1?
            name += parts[i] + ' ' # <--- ??
            address.append(name.strip()) # <--- I guess this is to wipe out whitespace front and back 
            address.append(parts[-1]) # <---???
            addresses.append(address) # <--- append the sublist into list

    return addresses
```

ones that I placed `???` beside it are the confusing parts. Could someone please clarify them?

Comment: Is the `address list` your desired result here?

Comment: yes, I don't know how the process works

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie to this site. I will try to follow along.

Comment: I think the indentation in your `load_addresses` function in the innermost loop is a little messed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
def line_split(line):
    ls = line.split()
    return [ls[0],' '.join(ls[1:-1]), ls[-1]]

with open(datafile) as fin:
    address_list = [ line_split(line) for line in fin ]
    #address_list = map(line_split,fin) # would also work too.
```

to explain the question marked lines:

```
for i in range(1, len(parts) - 1):
```

This loops over the indices in the list, but it skips the first and the last index.  A more idiomatic way to do this would be:

```
for part in parts[1:-1]:
```

and then you would replace `parts[i]` with `part` later in the loop.

```
name += parts[i] + ' ' # <--- ??
```

This takes `name` and adds `parts[i]` to it and a `' '`.  In other words, it is the same thing as any of the following:

```
name = name + parts[i] + ' '
name = "%s%s "%(name,parts[i])
name = "{0}{1} ".format(name,parts[i])
```

and the line:

```
address.append(parts[-1]) # <---???
```

appends the last part of the parts list to the `address` list.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your answer, but I am expecting explaination to my function not...another function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

```
>>> line = '100 Main Street'
>>> parts = line.split()
>>> name = ''
>>> len(parts)-1
2
>>> for i in range(1,2):
...    print parts[i] + ' '
...    print parts[-1]
...
Main # <-- there is an extra space here after 'Main'
Street
```